# Trying to login to a website clicking a button (Httpwebrequest - cookies)

Tags: c#, wordpress, cookies, httpwebrequest, webbrowser-control

I've just started playing around with C# few weeks ago. i got a task i am trying to perform and not sure if the way i do it now is the right approach.

I am trying to login to a website(in my case WordPress website- for lake of better options) and navigating in admin panel using C#

So far what I've done was creating a new project - Windows Form Application.

The following code - send a request to the website with password/username and other parameters as POST

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
    CookieContainer cookieJar2 = new CookieContainer(); // will use this later
    string testaa = ""; // will use this later
    string paramaters = "log=xxxx&pwd=xxxx&testcookie=1&redirect_to=http://www.example.com/wp-admin/&wp-submit=Log In";
    string strResponse;
    HttpWebRequest requestLogin = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.lyndatobin-howes.com/wp-login.php");
    requestLogin.Method = "POST";
    requestLogin.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
    requestLogin.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    requestLogin.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
    requestLogin.ContentLength = paramaters.Length;
    StreamWriter stOut = new StreamWriter(requestLogin.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
    stOut.Write(paramaters);
    stOut.Close();
}
```

I then have this code to to take the cookie of the response.

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)requestLogin.GetResponse();
foreach (Cookie c in response.Cookies)
{
    cookieJar2.Add(new Cookie(c.Name, c.Value, c.Path, c.Domain));
}
```

then i have this to read the response + close some streams.

```
StreamReader stIn = new StreamReader(requestLogin.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
strResponse = stIn.ReadToEnd();
string responseFromServer = stIn.ReadToEnd();
webBrowser1.DocumentText = responseFromServer;
stIn.Close();
response.Close();
```

And then i try using the above cookie for the page i am trying to access as follows :

```
HttpWebRequest requestLogin2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.example.com/wp-admin/");
requestLogin2.Method = "POST";
requestLogin2.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
requestLogin2.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
requestLogin2.CookieContainer = cookieJar2;
requestLogin2.ContentLength = paramaters.Length;
StreamWriter stOut2 = new StreamWriter(requestLogin2.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
stOut2.Write(paramaters);
stOut2.Close();

StreamReader stIn2 = new StreamReader(requestLogin2.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
strResponse = stIn2.ReadToEnd();
string responseFromServer2 = stIn2.ReadToEnd();
webBrowser1.DocumentText = responseFromServer2;
richTextBox2.Text += "\n\n\n" + responseFromServer2;
stIn.Close();
```

Well it doesn't work for some reason I've been trying this for a week now.

I tried displaying the header - after the first request to see what headers i get back. and then looked at the cookie i built (cookieJar2) and it seem they aren't the same..

Anyways any help on the matter would be awesome and highly appreciated. i tried to give as much details as i could.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and/or [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and compare the successfull requests (made with some browser) and the failing requests... then mimic the successfull requests in code by removing/adding whatever needed, very often [Cookies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer.aspx) are one of the "culprits" in such situations - sometimes it is a specific referer or similar...

Some sites use protective measures againt automated logins...

Besides the coding part: check whether automatically logging in this way is forbidden by their terms/conditions!

Comment: So, I am using fibbler,google chrome's inspect element and another tool for FF they all show about the same thing - that isnt the issue, i know which cookies i need but i cant seem to grab them no matter what i do. about forbidden or not - i am doing those tests on my own wordpress site that I've installed specially to check how log ins work - i didnt have another website to test is on... so for the legitimacy side - i am covered.

Comment: @YanivKossas IF there is absolutely no difference between the http communication via a browser and your C# code THEN you would not have any problem! Thus there must be a difference... another point is as I already wrote: some sites protect themselves from automated logins - check their terms/conditions and possibly the settings!

Comment: @YanivKossas another it is rather strange to use `HttpWebRequest` AND `WebBrowser` together - any reason why you are trying it this way ?

Comment: My C# code and the communication isn't the same obviously but that's because i cant seem to retrieve the cookies the right way. I use the webbrowser just like a textbox or any other way to show the output. I mean i have it for debugging purpose if that makes sense.

Comment: @YanivKossas I don't think that - use Fiddler on both (the succellfull browser and your code), you will certainly find some difference!

Comment: @YanivKossas regarding the webbrowser control... what you are doing is a really bad idea... the control is a "full-blown" Internet Explorer underneath with its own Cookie management etc. Since the returned HTML/JS can contain links etc. it might be interefering with your code in a bad way!

Comment: Ah - well i didnt think about it this way...  just wanted to have a debugger window to see actually what the results are instead of playing with HTML - i will try removing it.

Comment: @YanivKossas yes, I understand why you are using WebBrowser AND as I wrote it is a VERY BAD idea!

Comment: I am going to try again now Flibber again on both my script and the website and see if i missed something

Comment: The cookies that it send when accessing every page after login is:    wordpress_f8d4f8f31aa5e943c3743adfcf5eb8c0=admin%7C1334068559%7Cc32784988c3e00c80235bfe922ae3f28; wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check; wp-settings-1=m9%3Dc%26m10%3Do%26editor%3Dtinymce; wp-settings-time-1=1333895568; wordpress_logged_in_f8d4f8f31aa5e943c3743adfcf5eb8c0=admin%7C1334068559%7C11b30571ad09f2714c9e09893652ccc6    However when i retrieve the cookies i only get one of those 4 cookies ..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9831/discussion-between-yaniv-kossas-and-yahia)